# Rails dataTables add row not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

I'm using `gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', '~> 2.1.10.0.3'` in a Rails project.

I'm just starting an attempt to use the dataTable add row feature.

This is my JavaScript (Coffeescript):

```
t = $("#dataTableAdd").dataTable
  bfilter: true
  iDisplayLength: 25
  bLengthChange: true
  "sPaginationType": "bootstrap"
  oColVis:
    buttonText: "Hide/Show"
    bRestore: true
  sDom: "C<\"clear\">lrTtiXp"
  oTableTools:
    aButtons: [
      sExtends: "xls"
      sButtonText: "Save Excel"
    ,
      sExtends: "pdf"
      sPdfOrientation: "landscape"
      sPdfMessage: "pdf"
      mColumns: "visible"
      sButtonText: "Save PDF"
    ]

$("#addRow").on "click", ->
  t.row.add([
      "Name"
      "Description"
      "Type"
      "Count"
      "Manufacturer"
      "Man Date"
      "Purchase Date"
      "Purchase Price"
      "Actions"
      "Actions2"
  ]).draw()
  return
```

I'm getting this error when I click on the addrow button:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
```

It happens on the `t.row.add` line.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of:

```
t = $("#dataTableAdd").dataTable
```

try:

```
t = $("#dataTableAdd").DataTable
```

It looks like the old datatables API '`dataTable()`' does not support the function you are calling. Use the new API with: '`DataTable()`'. Read here for more info: https://datatables.net/blog/2014-02-04#API